# Consulta con INNER JOIN de 3 tablas me trae datos repetidos

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola estoy haciendo un **INNER JOIN** pero al ejecutar mi siguiente código me trae datos repetidos, creo que el problema es mi **sintaxis** de **mysql**

```
SELECT 4am_comsysn.agepersocli.keypercli, 4am_comsysn.agepersocli.codagencia, 4am_comsysn.agepersocli.codcli, 4am_comsysn.climae.nomcli, 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codper, 4am_comsysn.ageperso.nomper, 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codper
    FROM 4am_comsysn.agepersocli
    INNER JOIN 4am_comsysn.climae ON 4am_comsysn.agepersocli.codcli = 4am_comsysn.climae.codcli 
    INNER JOIN 4am_comsysn.ageperso ON 4am_comsysn.agepersocli.codPer = 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codper
ORDER BY 4am_comsysn.agepersocli.fecusr ASC;
```

los datos que me devuelve son:
[image: datos]

como pueden ver el Keypercli se duplica pero no se como solucionarlo y que solo me junte los datos una vez

Mis tablas son

Tabla: **agepersocli**

keypercli, codagencia, codcli, codper

Tabla **Climae**

nomcli,codcli,

Tabla **ageperso**

codper, nomper

Comment: Coloca un DER de las tablas involucradas y cómo se relacionan.

Comment: Usa `SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2,...`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta solo tengo duda de que es un DER, pero se relacionan por cocli y codper

Comment: creo que quiso decir "Diagrama entidad relación"

Comment: @αλρθα gracias ahora edito la pregunta

Comment: Usar `DISTINCT` va a eliminar las filas repetidas, pero puede darse el caso donde las filas sean distintas pero la columna `keypercli` sea la misma..... DER = Diagrama de Entidad Relación

Comment: DER es el diagrama lógico de la base de datos, luego se transforma en trablas, claves primarias, foráneas, etc.

Comment: @DamiánAlva me dio este error http://prntscr.com/nj962x es incompatible

Comment: Ese error es porque estás tratando de ordenar por una columna que no se encuentra en el `select`. Podés agregar la columna o cambiar el ordenamiento.... por los datos repetidos, en la consulta no veo error, sospecho que tu tabla `agepersocli` tenga los valores repetidos.

Comment: Sugiero que incluyas una muestra de los datos que hay en cada tabla, dos o tres filas por tabla es suficiente, y el resultado que producen. También, es mejor publicar los datos y resultados, no como imágenes, sino como texto. En mi caso, eso ayuda a realizar pruebas y escribir la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de los datos duplicados en los **inner** puede ser por varias razones.

1- Mismos valores en todas las columnas(duplicadas) consultadas, exceptuando un valor deberías de revisar la consulta general que haces ya que nosotros no contamos con el resultado de ella y ver si dentro de las columnas que estas consultando hay alguna que difiere.

2- Tablas Maestro/Detalle en ocasiones al utilizar **inners** manejamos la jerarquía de tablas maestro y detalle viendo como el punto anterior, podríamos tener un resultado en la tabla Maestro y 5 resultados en la Tabla detalle, considerar que las si lo campos que estamos consultando hacen referencia a la tabla Maestro y no a las Tablas detalle repetirá los valores N veces estén en las tablas detalle.

Verifica la información de las tablas que consultas, por que de los inner no llamas toda la información de las tablas, lo cual me genera duda si los campos pueden cambiar o tomar algun otro valor viendo desde la logica de maestros/detalle.

```
SELECT 
A.keypercli, 
A.codagencia, 
A.codcli, 
B.nomcli, 
C.codper, 
C.nomper, 
C.codper
FROM Agepersocli A
INNER JOIN Climae B ON A.codcli = B.codcli 
INNER JOIN Ageperso C ON A.codPer = C.codper
ORDER BY Agepersocli.fecusr ASC;
```

Toma en cuenta los valores que se generan por todos los campos de la tablas y verifica la información, verificando si alguna de ellas cambia o necesita un valor distintivo para quitar el duplicado ya que el **DISTINCT** quita los valores duplicados pero solo es una cortina a una mala sintaxis y el tiempo en que se ejecuta la consulta sera el mismo yendo a traer muchos campos y mostrando menos.

Saludos

Comment: si hay datos repetidos puedes usar group tambien ...